# MySQL Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax .. near line 1?

Tags: php, mysql-error-1064

I am working on a MySQL & PHP project. It is based on a Music Database. I am getting the following error when I go to http://andrewb1.sgedu.site/editgenres.php:

```
Error: SQL Error: 
Errno: 1064
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

I'm a bit confused how I am getting an error on Line 1 as the only thing there is the open php tag

The code for the editgenres.php is:

```
<?php

include 'dbconnect.php';

$sql = "select * from Genres where GenreID = " . $_REQUEST['GenreID'];
if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    echo "Error: SQL Error: </br>";
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "</br>";
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "</br>";

    exit;
}

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

?>

<form action="editgenressrv.php">
<input type="hidden" name="GenreID" value = "<?php echo $row["GenreID"]?>"/> 
GenreID:<input type="text" name="GenreID" value="<?php echo $row["GenreID"]?>"/></br>
GenreName:<input type="text" name="GenreName" value="<?php echo $row["GenreName"]?>"/></br>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Also, if needed here is the code for EditGenresSrv.php:

```
include 'dbconnect.php';

$sql = "update Genres set ";
$sql .= "GenreID = '" . $_REQUEST["firstname"] ."'," ;
$sql .= "GenreName = '" . $_REQUEST["lastname"] ."'," ;
$sql .= "where GenreID= " . $_REQUEST['GenreID']; 
if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    echo "Error: SQL Error: </br>";
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "</br>";
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "</br>";

    exit;
}
?>
<script>
window.location='genres.php';
</script>
```

If needed, here is dbconnect.php (although I've already tested it and its fine):

```
include 'dbconnect.php';

$sql = "insert into students (firstname,lastname,email) values (" . 
  "'" . $_REQUEST["GenreID"] ."','" .
  $_REQUEST["GenreName"] . "' ";

if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    echo "Error: SQL Error: </br>";
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "</br>";
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "</br>";

    exit;
}
?>
<script>
window.location='genres.php';
</script>
```

Here is the HTM file:

```
<form action="addgenressrv.php">
GenreID:<input type="text" name="GenreID"/></br>
GenreName:<input type="text" name="GenreName"/></br>

<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! The error is line 1 of your query.

Comment: It means that your `$_REQUEST['GenreID']` is blank. Can you add the form you're using to your question?

Comment: I just added the HTM file to the bottom of my post if that's what you meant?

Comment: Add `print_r($_REQUEST);` to the top of the script and see if it is populated. In your first form you have two items named `GenreID`

Comment: When I put this at the top: <?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
include 'dbconnect.php';

$sql = "select * from Genres where GenreID = " . $_REQUEST['GenreID'];              I get       Array ( ) Error: SQL Error: 
Errno: 1064
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: So the `$_REQUEST` array is empty which means you're not sending anything to the PHP for the SQL to process.

Comment: Where is the form that sends info to editgenres.php ?

Comment: one of the PHP files? you aren't referring to editgenresrv.php are you?

Comment: I don't see any form where the action is editgenres.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be carefull with the comma before where.

```
$sql = "update Genres set ";
$sql .= "GenreID = '" . $_REQUEST["firstname"] ."'," ;
$sql .= "GenreName = '" . $_REQUEST["lastname"] ."' " ;
$sql .= "where GenreID= " . $_REQUEST['GenreID'];
```

Comment: That isn't where the error is being reported from, but it would be the next syntax issue.

Comment: Why wouldn't there be a comma on that third line?

Comment: The error on line 1, is line 1 of the MySQL statement, not a PHP syntax error. You can use `"\n"` to break up the statement into multiple lines.

Comment: @fyrye Are you referring to : $sql = "select * from Genres where GenreID = " . $_REQUEST['GenreID'];   ? Why would that need multiple lines?  Or are you referring to editgenressrv.php with  $sql = "update Genres set ";
$sql .= "GenreID = '" . $_REQUEST["GenreID"] ."'," ;
$sql .= "GenreName = '" . $_REQUEST["GenreName"] ."' " ;
$sql .= "where GenreID = " . $_REQUEST['GenreID'];   ?

Comment: You referenced PHP code. The reported error in your question was the SQL error from `$mysqli->error`, not a PHP error. Effectively all of your queries will report on line 1, as they are only one line. The individual lines are concatenated to a single string value, supplied as the `$sql` argument to be executed by the mySQL service where the error is generated.  See https://3v4l.org/ItvoE So since PHP doesn't raise an error, it doesn't account for the lines where the code is written. You could use `echo "Error: SQL Error on line " . __LINE__ . "</br>";` to reference the PHP line the code is on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass GenreID to your page, check out following link

```
http://andrewb1.sgedu.site/editgenres.php?GenreID=1
```

and you will understand everything. If not then I will explain you.
there should be value for `$_REQUEST['GenreID']` from your previous page.

```
$sql = "select * from Genres where GenreID = " . $_REQUEST['GenreID'];
```

THis line giving your the error message because your are not passing your `GenreID` to the file `editgenres.php` whether using POST method or GET.

In your form put `<form action="editgenres.php">` and then

```
GenreID:<input type="text" name="GenreID"/></br>
GenreName:<input type="text" name="GenreName"/></br>
```

Because as you said error with `editgenres.php` then you must call this page by a form as above. check your **action** of your first page which will call `http://andrewb1.sgedu.site/editgenres.php`

Comment: @JayBlanchard he is passing to other service file `editgenressrv.php` not to  `editgenres.php` and error message is from `editgenres.php`. So the previous page which calls `editgenres.php` must send `GenreID`.

Comment: editgenres.php has <form action="editgenressrv.php"> . You are saying I should have a file editgenres.htm that has <form action="editgenres.php">
?